# XGBoost parallelization issue on macOS High Sierra

Tags: python, macos, openmp, xgboost, macos-high-sierra

I am using Anaconda environment on macOS High Sierra and could not run XGBoost with 8 thread even though I set the *nthread* parameter to 8.

The python code is like this. When I run it, I monitor the execution by looking at *htop*. There is only one process which is 100%.

```
clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(
     **xgb_params,
     n_estimators=1000,
     nthread=8
)
```

Then I searched on the internet and found this link. Some people refer this one and I followed it.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/Installing_XGBoost_on_Mac_OSX?lang=en

```
➜  ~ brew install gcc --without-multilib
Warning: gcc 8.2.0 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 8.2.0, run `brew reinstall gcc`
```

After seeing this info, I added the following lines to my xgboost config

```
export CC = gcc-8
export CXX = g++-8
```

When the build is done. I tried it again and nothing changed.

So, I kept searching the solution. I found this page.

https://clang-omp.github.io/

Then I ran the following line.

```
brew install llvm
```

And I tried to do the example in that site. I created a file, which is called hello.c, and put the following code inside.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
#pragma omp parallel
  printf("Hello from thread %d, nthreads %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), 
  omp_get_num_threads());
}
```

Then I tried to compile it as mentioned.

```
clang -fopenmp hello.c -o hello
```

It worked! I also tried gcc-8 as follows.

```
gcc-8 -fopenmp hello.c -o hello
```

It also worked. So, this is the output when I run *./hello*

```
➜  ~ ./hello 
Hello from thread 4, nthreads 8
Hello from thread 7, nthreads 8
Hello from thread 2, nthreads 8
Hello from thread 1, nthreads 8
Hello from thread 6, nthreads 8
Hello from thread 3, nthreads 8
Hello from thread 0, nthreads 8
Hello from thread 5, nthreads 8
```

So, I added gcc-8 in xgboost config file and gcc-8 is able to run in parallel with -fopenmp option as you can see. However, XGBoost does not run in parallel even though I compile it with this setting and set the nthread parameter to 8.

Is there any idea that I can try more?

**Edit 1**: I tried more complex code to ensure parellalization works. I tried [this code](https://gist.github.com/alexey-bataev/8c32e1ed74e6ef507fb8). The output shows 8 thread work. I also see it by typing *htop*.

```
➜  ~ clang -fopenmp OpenMP.c -o OpenMP
➜  ~ ./OpenMP 
---- Serial
---- Serial done in 37.058571 seconds.
---- Parallel
---- Parallel done in 9.674641 seconds.
---- Check
Passed
```

**Edit 2**: I installed gcc-7 and did same process. It did not work either.